# How to use a Proxy with Youtube API? (Python)

Tags: python, api, youtube, gdata

I'm working a script that will upload videos to YouTube with different accounts. Is there a way to use HTTPS or SOCKS proxies to filter all the requests. My client doesn't want to leave any footprints for Google. The only way I found was to set the proxy environment variable beforehand but this seems cumbersome. Is there some way I'm missing?
Thanks :)

Comment: "My client doesn't want to leave any footprints for Google"?  We're not going to help you spam people.

Answer (score 0):

Setting an environment variable (e.g. `import os; os.environ['BLAH']='BLUH'` **once** at the start of your program "seems cumbersome"?!  What *does* count as "non-cumbersome" for you, pray?